# How to customize the widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to customize the body alignment....the code is shown below.I am very new to flutter and I wanted to make a intro slider page. Everything is working fine but I am facing some issues in designing

I am using a PageViewModel widget and inside this I am having  3 things:

1. title
2. body
3. mainImage

now title is covering the top area and body is covering the bottom area and mainImage is covering the center area.

I want to have body at the center and it should be covering maximum height of page and i am not able to do that I have tried by giving the alignment but not able to achieve this so far.

```
   PageViewModel(
          pageColor: const Color(0xFF3F61DF),
          iconImageAssetPath: 'assets/slide3.png',
          body: Text('',style: style),
          title: Text(''),
          mainImage:SlideWidget1(),
         textStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyFont', color: 
         Colors.textcolor),
        ),
       @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'IntroViews Flutter', //title of app
            theme: ThemeData(
             primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ), //ThemeData
              home: Builder(
             builder: (context) => IntroViewsFlutter(
              pages,
             onTapDoneButton: () {
             Navigator.push(
             context,
             MaterialPageRoute(
                   builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                  ), //MaterialPageRoute
                );
               },
           pageButtonTextStyles: TextStyle(
           color: Colors.white,
           fontSize: 18.0,
          ),
         ), //IntroViewsFlutter
        ), //Builder
       ); //Material App
      }
     }




      class SlideWidget1 extends StatelessWidget {

         @override
             Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return Center(
                child: Card(
                elevation: 2,
                child: ClipPath(
                child: Container(
                height: 1500,
                child: Container(
                  height:1200,
                  width:300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: 
                       Colors.green, width: 5))),
                     color: Colors.white,
                     image: DecorationImage(
                             image: AssetImage("assets/slide1.png"),

                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                             ),
                        ),
               child:Align(
                 alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                 child: Text("Keep track of all your accounts 
                             anytime anywhere",
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: 
                    Colors.textcolor)),

                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
           );
          }
         }
```

Comment: looks like you have `Alignment.bottomCenter` for the `Text` widget instead of `Alignment.center`

Comment: You got solution of this one ?

Comment: I changed the widget from pageViewModel to PageView and added container as its child